# Hide SQL Server connection string in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access database that is being used as a Front end to a SQL Server database.  I have inherited responsibility for this from a company required.  I've found that the SQL Server's connection string, including IP Address, User and Password are all available.  Is there a way to either hide the COnnection string settings, or a way to encrypt these? The problem is that anyone who has a copy of this Access file, can extract the connection string and connect to the SQL Server database with minimal effort.

How can I hide the connection details?

Comment: I'm actually looking for a means to lock down any screen that shows connection string info. I want to hide not only the password but user name and the Server Name / IP Address.

Comment: You can't. You can make it difficult, but that's all. But without a password the information is useless.

Comment: Even if you were to miraculously make the server IP disappear totally, a network scanner would easily reveal the server IP + port. That info can't be hidden if you can't totally lock down both the network and the computer running Access.